# grunt-injector not injecting the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am using grunt-injector to inject client-side dependencies.

Here's how my "injector" part of my initConfig looks like:

```
    "injector": {
      "options": {
        "template": "public/dist/index.html",
        "destFile": "public/dist/index.gen.html"
      },
      "local_dependencies": {
        "files": {
          "public/dist/index.html": [
            "public/**/*.js",
            "public/**/*.css"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

and my public/dist/index.html reads

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- injector:css-->
    <!-- endinjector-->
  </head>
  <body ng-cloak ng-app="primary">
    <!-- injector:js-->
    <!-- endinjector-->
  </body>
</html>
```

and I did

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-injector");
```

and register "injector" as part of my task.

However, executing grunt will just generate, but not inject. to "index.gen.html" file.

What should I do? any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be that you need a space after the injector call, so instead of <!-- injector:css--> you have <!-- injector:css -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the trailing space. Since I was using Pug (formerly Jade) to compile my HTML, it was generating `<!-- injector:css-->` instead of `<!-- injector:css -->` (since the Pug-equivalent is `// injector:css`) and the trailing space was autoremoved by my editor.

Adding

```
"options": {
    "starttag": "<!-- injector:{{ext}}-->",
    "endtag": "<!-- endinjector-->"
},
```

fixed the problem